# Flush the buffer after receiving packets

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am using the below code for receiving TCP packets from a tool.

```
while(socket.Connected)
{
  var buffer = new byte[4096];
  int receiveLength = socket.Receive(buffer);
  if (receiveLength != 0)
  {

     byte[] response= new byte[4096];
     ProcessPacketData(buffer, out response);

     socket.Send(resposne);
  }
//Sleep(100);
}
```

When Using this code, the problem that I am facing is,for socket.Receive() function the buffer doesn't getting flushed. Every time, when calling the socket.Receive(buffer), the new data packets are getting appended with the old packets contained in the buffer. I want to avoid that situation. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I guess you should try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696993/socket-tcp-c-sharp-how-to-clear-input-buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Receive` does not receive packets. It receives any amount of bytes greater than zero bytes. Use the return value `receiveLength` to find out how much actually was received and process only that amount.